# Ionic 3 img src function binding freezes the application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

Hi im working with AngularFireStorage but my application freezing without any errors.

Content

```
showPhoto(refUrl) {
        const ref = this.storage.ref(`images/${refUrl}`);
        return ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise().then(img => {
        return img;
    });
}
```

Html

```
<div class="image-container" *ngFor="let photo of photos | photofilter">
    <img [src]="showPhoto(photo.image)">
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea, it does not give an error ?